# Update Parse Server on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, parse-server

I have my own Parse server running on an Ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean. I'm pretty new to running my own backend. How do I check what version of Parse Server I'm running and how do I update it to the latest version?

Comment: Did you install your parse-server?

Comment: Yes. I followed a walk through.

Comment: You used git to clone the source code and installed it, right?
So now you want to know the version of your running parse-server and how to update it?

Comment: I cloned and installed the parse-server-example. How do I update it to the latest version?

Comment: Do you want to update parse-server-example or parse-server?

Comment: parse-server-example. I should have made that more specific originally.

Comment: Check my answer please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open terminal (command line tool), then use "cd" command to navigate to your parse-server-example directory: **cd ...../parse-server-example/**
2. Pull latest source code from github with command: **git pull**
3. Install packages and dependencies: **npm install**
4. Run it: **npm run index.js**

If you want your server keep running you can install and use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty desperate searching for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the package.json file of parse-server . 
Or you can just use `npm list` to list all packages and their dependencies with version .